# Database Design - creating multiple checklists of various sizes

Tags: .net-core, database-design, entity-framework-core

My last question was closed due to being too vague, new more on point question here:

Hey all

I'm learning to develop using .NET Core and Angular, and am developing a WebApp to do this.  I'm trying to figure out what the best would to build a database is for a specific portion of the project. This is a checklists module that will allow users to create checklists with customized questions that they would be able to pull up and answer as they complete each item.  An example of what I'm looking to do is as follows:

- A user can create a checklist that has as many questions as they
  would like to create.
- The user can then pull that checklist up and provide the answers to
  each question.
- Answers will be either a string, boolean, checkbox options, image or
  various other types of input the user chooses when creating the
  checklist.

Knowing that one user may create 3 questions, and another may create 50 questions, what is the best way to design the table for this to store each question?  Would this be a table dedicated to just the name of the checklist, and then another with the list of questions and answers tied together via a join or one to many table?  What is the best practice for this?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A checklist is a list of to-do items that you check off when done.  You're creating a more comprehensive type list, the name of which, I'm not sure of.

Comment: "Would this be a table dedicated to just the name of the checklist, and then another with the list of questions and answers tied together via a join or one to many tables?" Yes.  I'm not sure what the answer table would look like, since according to your description, it can be a boolean, a string, an image, or something else.  You might want to look at a NoSQL database option for the question and answer.